# Android 6 - Removing Icon's Grey Padding

Tags: android, icons, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-launcher

My app's icon has been displaying fine on Android devices prior to 6.0. Now on 6.0 devices there's a thick dark grey padding around the icon (please see the lower left icon in screenshot). My icon image has a white background with rounded edges.

I've ensured my icons have the resolutions for xxhdpi (144x144) and xxxhdpi (192x192), and I've checked the APK files to see the icons properly placed in the corresponding res/drawable-xxxx folders.

I've also tried regenerating the icons using Android Studio and online Android icon makers, as well as placing them in drawable / mipmap folders, but the same problem persisted.

How do I allow the icon to expand to the full size without the dark grey padding?

Thank you.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: why use online icon genrator when android studio provides icon generation through vector studio or image studio. p.s. you can customize your icons to much higher extent in these two tools

Comment: And another thing is, you are getting that padding because of the custom launcher. its not the issue of Android 6, try same apk in Motorola, samsung or pixel which has native Android UI, you will not see those paddings

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Atif, actually I was manually creating the icon dimensions all the while and it worked fine, I was just trying the online generator today to see if it solves the problem. I'm running this on my Samsung phone, and it the same padding exists whether I tried the Google Now, Trebuchet or Apex launchers.

Comment: Can you upload your actual .png file somewhere like git and provide the link.

Answer (score 1):

Easily you can use android studio Image Asset

click on app folder.

> **File => new => Image asset => select icon type as launcher icons => you can select image and browse => adjust**
>   **padding,and color => next => finish.**
>   [image]

Comment: I've tried using the image asset generator but it didn't make any difference

Comment: @Andy did you trim or used 0 pading?

Comment: I've set Trim: No, Padding: 0%; Scaling: Shrink to fit; and Shape: none (so my rounded edges are preserved). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that configuration... as well as putting them in drawable and mipmap folders to see if there are any differences.

Comment: for using image asset you should use image with proper resolution. ie. original image.

Comment: Yes I'm using the original high-res image :) Apparently something is also messed up with my Android 6.0.1. No matter how I change the icon, the installed icon within the phone remains the old one. I tried rebooting the phone but still the same problem, thus it is hindering my debugging of icon padding. Is there any way to clear the system's icon cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136301/discussion-between-codfather-and-andy).

Answer (score 0):

First  : make sure that you icons are sliced probably without any padding.

Second : use mipmap folders for app launcher icons and make sure icons for all sizes.

Third  : uninstall you application, clean & build and install fresh one.

hope this can help

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. My icons don't have slicing, just a normal PNG image.. does that affect the padding for Android 6? It has been working fine all the while. I've tried placing them in mipmap folders too and cleaning the build but the same padding exists.

Answer (score 0):

That can be disabled by:

1. Go to **Settings** > **Display** > **Icon backgrounds**
2. Select **Icons only**